# Open Source Equivalent of AWS Flow Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

There many workflow system out there but I was wondering which one of the open source workflow management system is the closest to the AWS Flow Framework (with Amazon SWF like capability build in)?

Comment: The closest thing I know of is Activiti. BPM is really the closest equivalent.

Comment: Cannot give it is as an answer anymore. Cadence (https://github.com/uber/cadence) is an open source project built at Uber and closely resembles SWF API. It is at this point is already exceeding SWF in terms of features.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AWS Flow Framework itself is open source under [Apache 2.0 license](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/LICENSE.txt). Its source code is available on github: https://github.com/aws/aws-swf-flow-library.

**Update:**
If you need an open source solution that includes the service and is much more features rich check out [Temporal](https://temporal.io/).

Comment: There is now an official version of [AWS Flow Framework for Ruby](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsrbflowguide/welcome.html).


[aws-flow on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-flow-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon SWF is quite different from the other existing workflow systems :

- It is not trying to implement BPMN (we could say it is lower level than most workflow systems)
- It is focused on distributing tasks to heterogeneous systems (so you can run the activities on any platform, in any language.)

Besides the official Java Flow Framework, I only know :

- [Gordon (Ruby)](http://www.slideshare.net/jweiss/amazon-swf-and-gordon), but I'm not sure it's open-sourced yet
- [aws-swf-toolkit (Javascript/Node.js)](https://github.com/neyric/aws-swf-toolkit) (disclaimer: I'm the author of this one)

Comment: BPMN?   Do you mean BPMS (business process management services)?  The closest BPMN I could google was business process modelling notation.

Answer (score 0):

(Shameless post?) I started writing my own library (SimpleWorkflowFramework.NET) for use in C# and its available at https://github.com/sdebnath/SimpleWorkflowFramework.NET. It definitely could use some help if anyone is interested.