# Simple Workflow SWF for local testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, eucalyptus, amazon-swf

I am looking for an AWS (amazon web service) SWF (simple workflow) service that can be run locally for testing and development purposes. I've not seen anything like it available but I am aware of [ElasticMQ](https://github.com/adamw/elasticmq) which implements a subset of AWS SQS as a base component needed to build a SWF clone. I've also looked at [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) as a starting point.

Is anyone aware of a local service that could be used for local testing and development of an application using SWF?  I already have a Eucalyptus 3.3 instances for most of the rest of the requirements (S3, EC2, IAM, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware about any local implementation of the AWS SWF. As the service business logic is pretty involved creating such component is nontrivial.

If you are using AWS Flow Framework (available in Java and Ruby) then you can test your workflows using provided integration with unit testing frameworks. See [HelloWorldTest](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldTest.java) for a Java example.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but that doesn't quite match what we are trying to do. We really want a standalone service that emulates SWF if possible.

Comment: I found another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236575 that is worth reading.

Comment: Just use temporal.io which is an open source version of SWF. It runs locally without problem.